# add to array if is defined -php

Tags: php, arrays

i have this code

```
$courses = array("name_lic", "name_mes", "name_dou");
```

How i can add to array if `name_lic, name_mes, name_douc`are defined?

For example: `name_lic` is defined then, is insert in array, `name_mes` is not defined or is empty then is not inserted in the array and `name_dou` also.

basically the array only can have strings that are defined

in my example should be:

```
$courses = array("name_lic");
```

Comment: What do you mean by "defined strings"?

Comment: that have a value inserted by user, in my case, is not empty. Only the fields that have values are added to the array.

Comment: Does "inserted by user" mean "present in the `$_POST` array?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to guess that "inserted by user" means a value present in `$_POST` due to a form submission.

If so, then try something like this

```
$courses = array("name_lic", "name_mes", "name_dou");
// Note, changed your initial comma separated string to an actual array

$selectedCourses = array();
foreach ($courses as $course) {
    if (!empty($_POST[$course])) {
        $selectedCourses[] = $course;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like

```
if (isset($name_lic)) { 
    $courses[] = $name_lic;
}
```

... etc for name_mes, name_dou

Answer (score 1):

`isset` will return `TRUE` if the value is an empty string, which apparently you don't want. Try

```
if (!empty($_POST['name_lic'])){
    $courses[] = $_POST['name_lic'];
}

// etc
```

For example, if you want to do this for all values of $_POST:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
    if (!empty($value)){
        $courses[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if your code is:

```
$courses = array("name_lic, name_mes, name_dou");
```

then $courses is an array with only one key, you should remove the " " like this:

```
$courses = array("name_lic", "name_mes", "name_dou");
```

Now if you want to know if the array contains a key with the value "name_lic" you should use the function [in_array()](http://dk.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) like this:

```
if (in_array("name_lic", $courses)) {
  //Do stuff
}
```